# Sharepoint "Global Navigation" links dissapearing after save

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, navigation

I added custom xml site template and site was created.

When i am trying to modify default sharepoint navigation on page:
**/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx**

Changes for "Global Navigation" cannot be applied. "Global Navigation" folder becomes empty after "ok" button click.

And sometimes nodes in "Current Navigation" become sorted even if proprty set "Sort Manually" ("Current Navigation" can be saved without any problems!)

Whats gooing wrong with navigation???

Web feature:

```
 <Feature ID="541F5F57-C847-4e16-B59A-B31E90E6F9EA">
      <!-- Per-Web Portal Navigation Properties-->
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <Property Key="InheritGlobalNavigation" Value="false"/>
        <Property Key="IncludeSubSites" Value="true"/>
        <Property Key="IncludePages" Value="false"/>
      </Properties>
    </Feature>
```

In code configuration:

```
  if (publishingWeb.Navigation != null)
        {
            publishingWeb.Navigation.OrderingMethod = OrderingMethod.Manual;
            publishingWeb.Navigation.InheritGlobal = true;
            publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;
            publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites = false;

            publishingWeb.Navigation.InheritCurrent = false;
            publishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
            publishingWeb.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
        }

        publishingWeb.PagesList.EnableModeration = false;
        publishingWeb.Update();
```

Without this code i am facing same problems!

P.s. Only my site not working.

Unable to retrieve TopNavigationBar SPNavigationNodeCollection from Web at: /Pages/default.aspx. The SPNavigation store is likely corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you defining new site definition in onet.xml make sure that you dont removed default **navbars**! You can see which navbars is should be added by default in any sharepoint default onet.xml.  In other case any unexpected problems can appear!

```
    <NavBars>
  <NavBar 
    Name="$Resources:core,category_Top;" 
    Separator="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" 
    Body="&lt;a ID='onettopnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#' accesskey='J'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/a&gt;" 
    ID="1002" />
  <NavBar 
    Name="$Resources:core,category_Documents;" 
    Prefix="&lt;table border=0 cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0&gt;" 
    Body="&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' ID='100' alt='' border=0&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign=top&gt;&lt;a ID=onetleftnavbar#LABEL_ID# href='#URL#'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;" 
    Suffix="&lt;/table&gt;" 
    ID="1004" />
    ...
</NavBars>
```